# Counting the number of cycles in an Undirected Graph

Tags: java, graph, cycle-detection

### Question

Write a JAVA program to count the number of cycles in an Undirected graph.

### My approach:

I tried solving this using Depth First Search.

I found a program online that counts the cycles of length n in an undirected and connected graph.

The code is from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cycles-of-length-n-in-an-undirected-and-connected-graph/

I modified that by creating a function count(). Which checks the number of cycles in the graph for different lengths using a for loop. The code I've gotten so far is attatched below.

For the following graph,
[image]

The output I get is

[image]

However, isn't the answer supposed to be 3?

Following 3 unique cycles

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 0

0 -> 1 -> 4 -> 3 -> 0

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1

```
public class Main 
{
    public static final int V = 5;
    static int count = 0;
    static void DFS(int graph[][], boolean marked[],int n, int vert, int start) 
    {
        marked[vert] = true;
        if (n == 0) 
        {
            marked[vert] = false;
            if (graph[vert][start] == 1) 
            {
                count++;
                return;
            } 
            else
                return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
            if (!marked[i] && graph[vert][i] == 1)
                DFS(graph, marked, n-1, i, start);
        marked[vert] = false;
    }
    static int countCycles(int graph[][], int n) 
    {
        boolean marked[] = new boolean[V];
        for (int i = 0; i < V - (n - 1); i++) 
        {
            DFS(graph, marked, n-1, i, i);
            marked[i] = true;
        }
        
        return count / 2;
    }
    
   
    public static int count(int graph[][]) 
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int i=3;i<6;i++)    //i starts at 3 because the minimum length of a cycle is 3.
            count+=countCycles(graph,i);
        return count;
    }
    
    // driver code
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int graph[][] = {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}};
        System.out.println("Total cycles are "+count(graph));
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's counting them in both directions?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to step through this with your debugger.

Comment: I'd agree with tgdavies: the cycles are probably counted in both directions. After all, it is an _undirected_ Graph so `0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 0` and `0 <- 1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 0` are different cycles.

Comment: @tgdavies This makes sense! I'll check it out! thanks!!

Comment: @Thomas Yes!! I think this is what went wrong. I'll go check it using more test cases to make sure! Thank you

Comment: Having another look at the code you've posted there is "Hence the total count must be divided by 2 because every cycle is counted twice." - You seem to be doing that so this should not be the problem. But it seems your `count()` method is wrong: `countCycles()` seems to use the `n` parameter as a boundary and it seems to find cycles of length `n` at most. Since you're calling it for values 3, 4 and 5 it will find 3 cycles for value 4 and 5 and thus you're counting double.

Comment: @Thomas Yes! It makes sense now! I tried it for a few more test cases, and I get the right answer if I divide the return value of function count() by two!

Comment: I'd be careful with dividing by 2. Imagine you're adding longer cycles and now would run `countCycles()` for values 3, 4, 5 and 6 - you might then count the shorter cycles 3 times!. Also try try adding a single vertex to one of the cycles so that it has length 5 now. Would you still count all of them twice in your current setup?

Comment: One final note: you might not actually have to divide your final count at all. Just run through your code with a debugger and I assume you'll see the following: when you call `countCycles(graph,5);` this actually won't find any additional cycles of length 5 but `count` still has the value 6. So you're returning 3 from that method even though nothing has been found. Instead you might do the following: a) reset `count` at the start of `countCycles(...)` or b) don't return anything from `countCycles()`, remove the local `count` in `count()` and return the static `count` divided by 2.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you so much! Ill take these into account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this using DFS and Graph colouring method.

```
//Program to count the number of cycles in an Undirected Graph

import java.util.*;
class Graph
{
    static final int N = 100000;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static Vector<Integer>[] graph = new Vector[N];
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static Vector<Integer>[] cycles = new Vector[N];
    static int cyclenumber;
    
    // Function to mark the vertex with
    // different colors for different cycles
    static void dfs_cycle(int u, int p, int[] color,int[] mark, int[] par)
    {
        // already (completely) visited vertex.
        if (color[u] == 2)
        {
            return;
        }
        // seen vertex, but was not completely visited -> cycle detected.
        // backtrack based on parents to find the complete cycle.
        if (color[u] == 1)
        {
            cyclenumber++;
            int cur = p;
            mark[cur] = cyclenumber;
             // backtrack the vertex which are
            // in the current cycle thats found
            while (cur != u)
            {
                cur = par[cur];
                mark[cur] = cyclenumber;
            }
            return;
        }
        par[u] = p;
        // partially visited.
        color[u] = 1;
        // simple dfs on graph
        for (int v : graph[u])
        {
            // if it has not been visited previously
            if (v == par[u])
            {
                continue;
            }
            dfs_cycle(v, u, color, mark, par);
        }
        // completely visited.
        color[u] = 2;
    }
    
    // add the edges to the graph
    static void addEdge(int u, int v)
    {
        graph[u].add(v);
        graph[v].add(u);
    }

    //Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            graph[i] = new Vector<>();
            cycles[i] = new Vector<>();
        }
        
        //Modify edges accordingly
        addEdge(1, 2);
        addEdge(2, 4);
        addEdge(4, 3);
        addEdge(1, 3);
        addEdge(3, 5);
        addEdge(4, 5);
        addEdge(4, 6);

        int[] color = new int[N];
        int[] par = new int[N];
        int[] mark = new int[N];

        cyclenumber = 0;

        dfs_cycle(1, 0, color, mark, par);

        if(cyclenumber>0)
        {
            System.out.println("CYCLE DETECTED!");
            System.out.println("Number of cycles: "+cyclenumber);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("CYCLE NOT DETECTED");
        }
    }
}
```